# Are npm start and nodemon doing the same?

Tags: reactjs, parallax

I have a simple react parallax effect in my website and if I run npm start, it's not working and if I run nodemon, the parallex effect works perfectly fine.
Is there any reason ?

Thanks by advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`npm start` is just a shortcut to run node commands. You can use npm start to run nodemon. Nodemon on the other hand monitor changes in the code so you don't have to constantly restart your server

```
"scripts": {
  "start": "nodemon server.js"
},
```

Although you can write anything you want in the start script, the convention is to run your server file.

Also you don't have to use nodemon. It is just a nice to.

```
"scripts": {
  "start": "node server.js"
},
```

In your case, since you are using reactjs your npm start is for the development server

Comment: Glad it works @AntoineBottin ! Anyway I would greatly appreciate it if you set my answer as the best answer if it helped you out. Cheers